# Using VirtualWire and RCSwitch in same PRoject

Tags: virtualwire

I have the problem, that I want some Arduinos communicate in a wireless mesh network using the VirtualWire library but also be able to receive (and send) codes for my rc sockets using the RCSwitch library.

I have some Arduinos using VirtualWire and some devices using the hx2262 IC for RC-Decoding.

I want to send and receive messages between the Arduinos (each message must be at least 10 bytes long) and also be able to send and receive messages from the hx2262 RC power sockets.

My idea would be to use VirtualWire for inter Arduino communication and RCSwitch for the power sockets. Both work fine as long as I do not put both libraries on the same controller.

Does anyone have an idea to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution: Just use both libraries. The problem I head: VirtualWire uses Pin numbering, RCSwitch uses Interrupt numbering. That was the reason, why it did not work.